# How to set ttl based on response object in spring Cacheable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have below use case for Cache. I am using `@Cacheable` annotation and it looks something like this:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "sampleCache", key = "#customerId", cacheResolver = "sampleCacheResolver")
public @ResponseBody SampleResponse getSampleMethod(String customerId) {
}
```

TTL is set in `sampleCacheResolver`. However I have a requirement where I have to change the TTL based on the response object. For example, in the response object if say `SampleResponse.month` is current month, I want to set the ttl to 1 min, else I want to leave the default value of 3 mins.

Since the `sampleCacheResolver` is getting called at the request level, I am not sure how I can update the ttl based on the response.

Comment: Try using conditional caching as shown here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial May be you can define two different caches depending on two different conditions.

Comment: @OnurBaştürk Problem for me is that , conditional TTL needs to be decided based on the response.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with *[Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8/reference/html/integration.html#cache)* out of the box.

Spring is very [clear](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8/reference/html/integration.html#cache-specific-config) that neither TTL (Time To Live) nor TTI (Idle Timeout) expiration policies (or even Eviction policies for that matter) are handled by the abstraction, and for good reason.

Expiration and Eviction implementations are caching provider specific and many have different possible actions when entries expire or are evicted.

It's rather peculiar to apply TTL to the response, particular given that TTL is a set timeframe.

At any rate, you have 2 options.

First, some caching providers and their supporting Spring bits offer capabilities close to what you are seeking.

For instance, I work on Spring Boot, Session and Data for [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/), which can [serve as a caching provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction) in *Spring's Cache Abstraction*.

1 of the features I support is entry level (that is, entity) expiration policies via an annotation-based configuration model.  See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:region:expiration:annotation).  Of course, this is made possible by Apache Geode itself given it's ability to express custom expiration policies.  That is, the implementation of entry level TTL using annotations is based on Apache Geode's [`CustomExpiry`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CustomExpiry.html) interface.

Another way to handle entry/entity or response TTL is to override/extend Spring's Cache Abstraction.  The 2 primary interfaces in the abstraction is the [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) and [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) interfaces.

In your case, you would implement the `Cache` interface to include the TTL logic you need.  You `Cache` (TTL) implementation would wrap the actual caching provider implementation (e.g. ***EhCache*** [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheCache.html)).  Then you must implement the `CacheManager` interface to wrap the caching provider `CacheManager` implementation (again, the  ***EhCache*** [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheCacheManager.html)).  Your `CacheManager` implementation exists soley to create instances of your TTL enabled `Cache` implementation wrapping the provider's `Cache` implementation, when called upon by the framework.  Essentially, your TTL enabled `Cache` implementation is enhancing, or [decorating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) the caching provider's `Cache` implementation with the TTL logic you require.

Yet another possible solution would be to use [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8/reference/html/core.html#aop).  Indeed, many of Spring's features like Caching or Transaction Management (demarcation) is handled by Spring AOP.  A carefully crafted AOP Aspect could wrap the Caching Aspect and contain the TTL logic you require.  You must be sure that the TTL AOP Aspect comes after Spring's Caching Aspect, which can be handled by bean ordering.

I did not provide an example for your exact use case this time.  However, I have answered questions that required a "custom" implementation of Spring's `Cache` and `CacheManager` interfaces before.  For your reference, you can refer to my [example](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/NonExistingCacheSafeCacheManagerWrapperIntegrationTests.java) to see how you might implement your own `Cache`/`CacheManager` combination.

Before going down the paths I presented, I encourage you to explore your caching provider to see if it affords you the TTL functionality you are after.  You should choose an appropriate caching provider based on your needs and requirements.

I know this is a lot of information, but I simply wanted you to have options and to think about the problem from multiple angles.

---

Comment: 1 other thing to keep in mind, Spring's Cache Abstraction operates on the premise that any entry is not in the cache if the `Cache.get(key)` method returns `null`.  It does not matter if the entry simply did not exist in the first place, was evicted or has expired.  Returning a `null` value is essential in informing the caching aspect of the appropriate action to do next.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I will explore this and try to add some custom logic.